# Is there a way to restrict container access for user in Docker?

Tags: docker, archlinux, user-permissions

I'm using a Docker machine to host some process such as game servers with friends. I want to give access to CLI of some containers for some users (and only for that), so that they cannot interfer eachothers. I don't want those to be roots on this server.

A solution might be to create users, allow them to perform certains commands in adequation with their containers (such as sudo docker attach ) and let them do everything. I would like to know if there is another, better and proper way to do it so.

Do you have done any experimentation of this kind ?

Thanks.

Comment: How about creating aliases to `docker exec` commands, and on the host somehow allowing terminal users only to exec those aliases ? I don't know the later part if it's possible.

Comment: Anyone who can run any `docker` command can trivially get unrestricted root access on the system, full stop.

Comment: Unfortunately it’s not possible. Host ssh server in your container and give them ssh access instead.

Comment: @Niloct I was thinking about doing this, but it seems to not be the proper way, as said David Maze. Setting an OpenSSH server on each process could be a more secure way to do what I want...

Comment: Are you aware that portainer does allow to create users/groups and assign ressources, e.g. containers to them? Within portainer, they could access container logs and terminals. With portainer you would not even require them to have access to your docker host or run sshd instances inside the containers.

Answer (score 3):

Why not creating a separate Docker container for each service?

So in other words, You create one container for each friend, and on each container you create a user which is a member in `sudo` (so your friend will be the root of his own container). Then install openssh-server, and give each of your friends the SSH access data (his username and password) to his container. This way they can do what ever they want, without affecting each other.

Of course do not forget to forward the SSH connection (and any other connections of the services you want) from the host to the container.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly as standing there

[Why doesn't Docker support multi-tenancy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584841/why-doesnt-docker-support-multi-tenancy)

docker doesn't support multi-tenancy so you cannot isolate users from each other.

Edit: one of the possible solutions is to create SSH server in every container and then let your users to connect directly via SSH to container instead of using host machine.