# How can I restrict container communication

Tags: docker

How can I allow only my `API` container to talk to my `DB` container but not other ones like `web` or `mq` containers ?

I know how to interlink all those using `networks` but not sure how to achieve the above scenario ?

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56394893/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-container-access-for-user-in-docker) can be helpful, Docker doesn't support multi-tenancy, So i guess you can do what you want inside the DB container, by adding a firewall rule. this was added as a comment as am not 100% sure if there is another way.

Comment: Put them on different networks: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε : Yea, I checked that :) but wanted to explore to understand whether its possible using one/single network